# Vite error during build - [vite:css] [postcss] - font urls are relative paths

Tags: vite

Vue Version : 2.6
Vite Version : 3.1.4

I receive the following error while trying to build my vite app.

```
[vite:css] [postcss] The "fileName" or "name" properties of emitted files must be strings that are neither absolute nor relative paths, received "C:/Users/user/vsc-workspace/fds-widgets-portal-showcase/vue/assets/fonts/Grand_Hotel/GrandHotel-Regular.ttf".
file: C:/Users/user/vsc-workspace/fds-widgets-portal-showcase/vue/assets/scss/main.scss:undefined:undefined
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from '@/App.vue';
import router from '@/router';
import { store } from '@/store/store';

// Global CSS styles
import '@/assets/scss/main.scss';
import 'typeface-roboto';

export default class FdsAware {
   vueInstances = {};

   constructor() {
       this.vueInstances = {};
   }

   async init(
       elementId,
       application = false,
   ) {
       // run the vue application
       if (!application) {
           // eslint-disable-next-line no-new
           new Vue({
               el: elementId,
               router,
               store,
               render: (h) => h(App),
           });
       } else {
           // library build
           this.vueInstances[elementId] = new Vue({
               el: elementId,
               store,
           });
       }

       return true;
   }
}
```

vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { createVuePlugin as vue } from 'vite-plugin-vue2';
import { createSvgPlugin as svgLoader } from 'vite-plugin-vue2-svg';
import path from 'path';
import rollupNodePolyFill from 'rollup-plugin-node-polyfills';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

//Used widgets-template as point of reference.

// Proxy Localhost
const LOCALHOST = 'http://localhost:5005';
    
    
//Configuration
const config = defineConfig({
    base: '/',
    root: path.resolve(__dirname, 'vue'),
    resolve: {
        alias: [
            {
                // vue @ shortcut fix
                find: '@/',
                replacement: `${path.resolve(__dirname, 'vue')}/`,
            },
            {
                find: 'vue',
                replacement: path.resolve(
                    __dirname,
                    'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
                ),
            },
            {
                // this is required for the SCSS modules
                find: /^~(.*)$/,
                replacement: 'node_modules/$1',
            },
        ],
    },
    server: {
        port: 8080,
        fs: {
            // Allow serving files from one level up to the project root
            allow: ['..'],
        },
        proxy: {
            '^/api': {
                target: LOCALHOST,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
            '^/api|chartiq/.*': {
                target: LOCALHOST,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
            '^/cdn': {
                target: LOCALHOST,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
            '^/download': {
                target: LOCALHOST,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        // Vue2
        // https://github.com/underfin/vite-plugin-vue2
        vue({
            target: 'esnext',
        }),
        svgLoader(),
    ],
    esbuild: {
        minify: true,
        treeShaking: true,
    },
    publicDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    build: {
        minify: 'terser',
        emptyOutDir: true,
        outDir: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/public'),
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [rollupNodePolyFill(), svgLoader()],
            output: {
                // Workaround via https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4863
                assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                    if (assetInfo.name === 'style.css') {
                        return 'fds-aware.css';
                    }

                    return assetInfo.name;
                },
            },
        },
        target: 'es2021',
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
        // Node.js global to browser globalThis
            define: {
                global: 'globalThis',
            },
        },
    },

});

export default config;
```

Most of the font urls in my css and scss files are with relative paths as below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Grand Hotel";
  src: url('../fonts/Grand_Hotel/GrandHotel-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

I also use a a postcss.config.js file to add the autoprefixer plugin in order to make my svgs load in my app. Is there something I am missing?

I undertstand that after importing my global css files in my main.js vite tries to build the app but it doesn't like the relative/absolute paths it comes across. Is there a way to transform this urls into something that vite can read?